# send array to csv file - simulation too slow

Tags: arrays, vba, csv, export

I automated a montecarlo simulation for stock and option prices that runs 10 thousand paths for 606 trading days.  All and all it works fine, the problem is that is slow.  The slow part of the code is when it has to write an array of say 400 x 10000 to the spreadsheet, then export it into a new CSV file and save it.

It does this for a 25 option portfolio (it takes 1 minute per option.)  So overall it takes 25 minutes, which is unacceptable.  How can I write directly to CSV the arrays of data that I am filling with the simulation?  I need to keep all stock prices, option prices and total portfolio value.   Below is the code that I have created for this.

```
    Sub Background_simulation()

0   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
1   Windows("Option Portfolio Simulation v7.xlsm").Activate
2   Sheets("Export").Activate
3   Dim Arr() As Variant
4   ArrStock = Range("F11:NTU616")
6   ArrOption = Range("F621:NTU1226")
7   Sheets("Export").Activate

8   Dim DestinationStock As Range
9   Set DestinationStock = Range("F11")

10  Dim DestinationOption As Range
11  Set DestinationOption = Range("F621")
12  Dim RAND(1 To 606, 1 To 10000) As Variant
13  Paths = Range("D6").Value

15  Dim Option_Paths(1 To 606, 1 To 10000) As Variant
16  Dim St_Paths(1 To 606, 1 To 10000) As Variant
17  Dim Options_Total(1 To 606, 1 To 10000) As Variant
18  FromOption = Range("D7").Value
19  UpToOption = Range("D8").Value
20  Sheets("Portfolio").Select
21  Let MaxExpirationOfSet = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("BC2:BC26").Value)
22  Sheets("Export").Select

23  For a = 2 To 606
24  For b = 1 To Paths
25  Randomize
26  RAND(a, b) = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormInv(RND(), 0, 1)
27  Next
28  Next

31  For Option_Nr = FromOption To UpToOption
32  Sheets("Export").Select
33  Range("F11:NTU616").Select
34  Selection.ClearContents
35  Range("F621:NTU1226").Select
36  Selection.ClearContents
38  Range("B1").Select
39  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Option_Nr
42  Calls = Range("L3").Value
43  If Calls = 0 Then GoTo 2010
44  St = Range("G2").Value
45  Rf = Range("G3").Value
46  Sigma = Range("G4").Value
47  dt = 1 / 250
48  mrn = Rf - (1 / 2) * Sigma ^ 2
49  X = Range("L5").Value
50  Expiration_Date = Range("D4").Value

120 For b = 1 To Paths
130 RAND(1, b) = 1
140 St_Paths(1, b) = St
150 Option_Paths(1, b) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(St - X, 0) * Calls
160 Options_Total(1, b) = Options_Total(1, b) + Option_Paths(1, b)
170 Next

190  For a = 2 To Expiration_Date
200  For b = 1 To Paths
600  St_Paths(a, b) = St_Paths(a - 1, b) * Exp(mrn * dt + Sigma * (dt) ^ (1 / 2) * RAND(a, b))
700  Option_Paths(a, b) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(St_Paths(a, b) - X, 0) * Calls
701  Options_Total(a, b) = Options_Total(a, b) + Option_Paths(a, b)
703  Next
704  Next

705  For a = (Expiration_Date + 1) To MaxExpirationOfSet
706  For b = 1 To Paths
707  St_Paths(a, b) = St_Paths(a - 1, b)
710  Option_Paths(a, b) = Option_Paths(a - 1, b)
711  Options_Total(a, b) = Options_Total(a - 1, b)
712  Next
730  Next

740 Sheets("Export").Select
750 Range("F11:NTU616").Select
760 Selection.ClearContents
770 Range("F621:NTU1226").Select
780 Selection.ClearContents
790 Range("A1").Select

800 DestinationStock.Resize(UBound(ArrStock, 1), UBound(ArrStock, 2)).Value = St_Paths
810 DestinationOption.Resize(UBound(ArrOption, 1), UBound(ArrOption, 2)).Value = Option_Paths

830 Sheets("Export").Copy
840 Range("F620").Select
845 ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:= _
        "C:\Users\pmesples\Desktop\Options\Option Portfolio Simulation v7.xlsm", Type _
        :=xlExcelLinks

850 ChDir "C:\Users\pmesples\Desktop\Options"
860 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\pmesples\Desktop\Options\" & Option_Nr & ".csv", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False


900  ActiveWindow.Close
1000 Sheets("Export").Select

1001 Range("F" & 620 + MaxExpirationOfSet & ":NTU" & 620 + MaxExpirationOfSet).Select
1002 Selection.Copy
1003 Sheets("Results").Select
1004 Cells(5, Option_Nr + 3).Select
1005 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

1006 Sheets("Export").Select
1010 Range("F11").Select
1020 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
1030 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
1040 Selection.ClearContents
1050 Selection.End(xlDown).Select
1060 Range("F621").Select
1080 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
1090 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
2000 Selection.ClearContents
2005 Range("A1").Select
2010 Next

2015 Range("B1").Select
2016 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 26
2020 DestinationOption.Resize(UBound(ArrOption, 1), UBound(ArrOption, 2)).Value = Options_Total
2030 Sheets("Export").Copy
2040 Range("F620").Select
2045 ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:= _
        "C:\Users\pmesples\Desktop\Options\Option Portfolio Simulation v7.xlsm", Type _
        :=xlExcelLinks

2050 ChDir "C:\Users\pmesples\Desktop\Options"
2060 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\pmesples\Desktop\Options\26.csv", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False


2100  ActiveWindow.Close
2110 Sheets("Export").Select
2215 Range("B1").Select
2120 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 1


End Sub
```

Comment: If you are looking for speed, using Excel VBA is not your best option. Use VB.NET instead and write the CSV file directly, bypassing Excel altogether. Your slowest factor is Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get rid of selects and selections to speed up the macro, like:

```
32  Sheets("Export").Select
33  Range("F11:NTU616").Select
34  Selection.ClearContents
```

could be replaces by

```
32  Sheets("Export").Range("F11:NTU616").ClearContents
```

but you probably lost most of valuable seconds while saving file, as you already have noticed. Indeed, you could try export to file, see my subroutine:

```
Private Sub PrintToCSV(sFileName As String, rng As Range)
Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileContent As String
Dim cl As Range

FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\something something\" & sFileName & ".csv"

TextFile = FreeFile

Open FilePath For Output As TextFile

For Each cl In rng
    Print #TextFile, cl.Value
Next cl

Close TextFile
End Sub
```

But, generally speaking, VBA is scripting language, so it is slow. I am not sure if writing to file will be faster than saving as, but you may try.

Comment: Thank you @MarcinSzaleniec.  I have tried to use your subroutine, but i couldn't make it work as a part of my routine.  How do I transfer my arrays into the Integer and Strings you define?

Comment: your arrays are ranges transferred to arrays, so use ranges directly. Like Range("F11:NTU616") instead of arrStock. But I am in concord with braX, you are unlikely to gain significant results in VBA. Nevertheless, your code may be optimalised.

Comment: Thank you again Marcin! have a nice day.